# How to change the default jquery validation dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery validation in a contact form. The success message is shown in the alert box but I want to use a bootstrap success message instead.

```
//On click of submit button 
$("#submit").click(function(){
$("#submit").css({"cursor":"default","box-shadow":"none"});
alert("Form Submitted Successfully..!!");
```

I'd like to use the HTML div in jQuery:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
<strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
var html = '<div class="alert alert-success">
<strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
</div>';
```

now append or prepend it anywhere you want on success event:-

```
$("#submit").click(function(event){ 
$("#submit").css({"cursor":"default","box-shadow":"none"}); 
//alert("Form Submitted Successfully..!!"); 
var html = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.</div>';
$('form').prepend(html);
event.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: yes offcourse you can do, instead if alert you use my above code.

Comment: I use it like this $("#submit").click(function(){
 $("#submit").css({"cursor":"default","box-shadow":"none"});
 //alert("Form Submitted Successfully..!!");
  var html = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.</div>';
 }); but its not working

Comment: can u tell me in this line [$('form').prepend(html); ]  form is form name?

Comment: you can use a class, i have used form tag, if you have single form on page, you can consider it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Sweet Alert](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/). It's a library for custom bootstrap UI alert boxes. For a success message, just inlcude the js file and call this from your success function

```
swal(
 'Message 1',
 'Message 2',
 'success'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume below source

```
`<html>
    <style>
        .message{display:none;}
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="message">
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
            </div>  
        </div>
        <form>
            !! form content over here
            <input type="button" id="submit" />
        </form>
        <script>
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                $("#submit").css({"cursor":"default","box-shadow":"none"});
                $(".message").show();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>`
```

Hope this helps you!!!